# Scaling Backgrounds in CSS

Tags: html, css, background

This isn't exactly about making background images in CSS for a site, so don't mark it as a duplicate just yet.

I need to replicate the following background, but in CSS. I have a variety of gradients implemented on the site but this is more like a darkening around the edges of the screen, and I don't know how to implement this, particularly in CSS. If there's a good way to do this with images please let me know.

[image: Background Example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try inset [`box-shadow`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/) http://jsfiddle.net/46JxH/

```
box-shadow:inset -70px 0 200px -30px rgba(0,0,0,.75);
```

Or background image with [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/CSS/background-size):100% 100%;.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using images, you can try `CSS3` **background-size:cover**

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can read more [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)